# Fixing a Dictionary Comprehension for a Nested For Loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, big-o

I'm learning about comprehensions, i.e. List Comprehensions and Dictionary Comprehensions. I'm wanting to use more comprehensions to scale up my code. Right now, I'm trying to convert this method, "parse sentences" that I had written as part of a web scraping class and I want to rewrite it as a dictionary comprehension.

```
def parse_sentences(text_str):
    """
    :param text_str: list of text that needs to be divided by periods
                    at end of sentence.
    :return: list of the individual sentences for every element
            of the list
    """
    # Define list to hold the individual sentences.
    split_text_strings = []
    
    # Loop through each element of the text.
    for i in text_str:
        split_i = i.split('.')
        for j in split_i:
            last = len(split_i) - 1
            if split_i[last] == '':
                split_i.pop(last)
            split_text_strings.append(j)
    
    return split_text_strings
```

Basically, it takes a list of text in the form ['This is a sentence. This is a great sentence.', 'Have you not heard of this sentence. Probably the best sentence I ever read.'] and returns another list split_text_strings with a sentence for each element like this. ['This is a sentence', 'This is a great sentence', 'Have you not heard of this sentence', 'Probably the best sentence I ever read']. Here's my attempt to convert this into a dictionary comprehension

```
def parse_sentences(text_str):
    """
    :param text_str: list of text that needs to be divided by periods
                    at end of sentence.
    :return: list of the individual sentences for every element
            of the list
    """
    split_text_strings = {(i, j): i.split('.') for i in text_str for j in text_str[text_str.index(i)]}
    return split_text_strings
```

I know that the '(i, j): i.split('.') for i in text_str' is the outer loop and the other for loop is the inner loop. But I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why did you add the tag `big-o`? Seems random.

Comment: Oh, because doesn't big-O have to do with algorithm complexity? I was trying to make my algorithm run more efficiently so I started studying Big-0 notation and time complexity

Comment: Big-O is about algorithmic complexity, but your question doesn't seem to be. The mere fact that you are interested in efficiency doesn't make this a big-O question. Otherwise, almost every question on Stack Overflow would be tagged with it.

Answer (score 0):

**What does not work?**
(1) The first function returns a list, while the second function returns a dictionary. Note that the description of the function is also a dictionary.
(2) There is a potential issue with duplicate or next to duplicate sentences. The input `['I love StackOverflow.', 'I love StackOverflow']` will be processed to `['I love StackOverflow', 'I love StackOverflow']` in the first case, but may cause duplicate keys for the dictionary comprehension. It results in missing data.
(3) `(i, j): i.split('.') for i in text_str for j in text_str[text_str.index(i)]` does the following. Say, `text_str = ['b.c']`. Then, `i='b.c'`. `j` iterates first over 'b.c', then `j` takes values `'b', '.', 'c'`. Then, the result is

```py
{
  ('b.c', 'b'): ['b', 'c'],
  ('b.c', '.'): ['b', 'c'],
  ('b.c', 'c'): ['b', 'c']
}
```

and it is not what you want.

**What you want to do**
I think you want to have the key to be as follows: the sequential number of the string in the `text_str` (which should be called `text_arr`, btw) and the sequential number of sentence within substring. For example, `['a...', 'b.c']` would be represented as

```py
{
  (0, 0): 'a',
  (1, 0): 'b',
  (1, 1): 'c'
}
```

In this case, we need to determine the sequence of strings. The outer loop is

```py
(i, ?): ?? for i, string in enumerate(text_str)
```

We fill out the question marks in a moment. We need to parse each string, so we need to consider `string.split('.')` and go over all sentences. This gives us the following answer

```py
(i, j): sentence for i, string in enumerate(text_str) for j, sentence in enumerate(string.split('.'))
```

Finally, we need to filter out empty strings as follows:

```py
(i, j): sentence for i, string in enumerate(text_str) for j, sentence in enumerate(string.split('.')) if sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you say dictionary when the code clearly says list twice.
Anyways, you can always use list comprehension. `for elem in text_str` is the outer loop and `for segment in elem.split('.')` is the inner one. If have extra requirements like removing duplicates, might consider a `set`.

```
split_text_strings = [segment for elem in text_str for segment in elem.split('.')]
```